# Why doesn't Go's time.Parse() parse the timezone identifier?

Tags: go

Consider the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

const (
    format = "2006 01 02 15:04 MST"

    date = "2018 08 01 12:00 EDT"
)

func main() {
    aloc, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")
    eloc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Europe/Berlin")
    tn, _ := time.Parse(format, date)
    tl, _ := time.ParseInLocation(format, date, aloc)

    fmt.Println(tn) // Says +0000 despite EDT being -0400
    fmt.Println(tn.In(eloc)) // Expect 18:00, but get 14:00
    fmt.Println(tl) // Correctly -0400
    fmt.Println(tl.In(eloc)) // Correctly 18:00
}
```

You can also try it out on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8ppyAssl8qv).

When I run it, I get this result (both on my own system and through the Playground):

```
2018-08-01 12:00:00 +0000 EDT
2018-08-01 14:00:00 +0200 CEST
2018-08-01 12:00:00 -0400 EDT
2018-08-01 18:00:00 +0200 CEST
```

I had expected the first and third line to be the same, and the second and fourth to be the same.

It seems to me that Go's time library doesn't parse the "EDT" timezone identifier I've written in the date string, despite it being part of the format.

My own system (Fedora 26) also recognises EST/EDT as a timezone:

```
$ TZ='America/New_York' date 080112002018
Wed  1 Aug 12:00:00 EDT 2018
```

Of course, as you can see, I can force the issue by using `ParseInLocation()`, but that's only useful if I know the timezone *beforehand*.  Otherwise I need to parse the 'EDT' part of the date string into 'America/New_York' myself.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like the godoc for the Parse function answers your question or am I missing something: ... "If the zone abbreviation is unknown, Parse records the time as being in a fabricated location with the given zone abbreviation and a zero offset. This choice means that such a time can be parsed and reformatted with the same layout losslessly, but the exact instant used in the representation will differ by the actual zone offset. To avoid such problems, prefer time layouts that use a numeric zone offset, or use ParseInLocation."

Comment: But why would 'EDT' be unknown?  A lot of their examples uses 'CEST', so I tried the reverse, but it's the same problem.  'CEST' gets parsed (without `ParseInLocation()`) to +0000 (not +0200).

Comment: Your example above worked for me with CEST producing `2018-08-25 12:00:00 +0200 CEST` for plain `Parse` with CEST in the date string. I really have no idea why EDT would be unknown, but then my own timezone is CET/CEST so I hope that one is known to the parser :)

Comment: Interesting problem. See https://golang.org/src/time/format.go#764  "When parsing a time with a zone abbreviation like MST, if the zone abbreviation has a defined offset in the current location, then that offset is used...."

Comment: OK, I only tested the 'CEST' change on the Playground.  On my own system, it works as expected.  So the Playground has no timezones, basically.

Comment: TImezone specifications like "EDT" are ambiguous. I can think of at least three different places on the planet that that might refer to, all of which have different timezones/daylight saving rules.

Comment: EST/EDT would be daylight savings agnostic.  They are just names for specific offsets to UTC.  GMT, UTC and WET are all the same.  If EDT always means -0400, then it doesn't matter what locations on the planet it refers to.  If you can name a timezone called EDT that's not -0400, then I'll grant you that.  But as far as I know, timezone abbreviations don't tend to overlap (I could be wrong).

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [time#Parse](//golang.org/pkg/time#Parse):

> When parsing a time with a zone abbreviation like `MST`, if the zone
> abbreviation has a defined offset in the current location, then that offset
> is used.

The key here is "current location". For me, that is `CST`. Using this works as
expected:

```
package main
import "time"

func main() {
   t, e := time.Parse(time.RFC1123, "Wed, 01 Aug 2018 12:00:00 CST")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   s := t.String()
   println(s == "2018-08-01 13:00:00 -0500 CDT")
}
```

> If the zone abbreviation is unknown, Parse records the time as being in a
> fabricated location with the given zone abbreviation and a zero offset.

```
package main
import "time"

func main() {
   t, e := time.Parse(time.RFC1123, "Wed, 01 Aug 2018 12:00:00 EDT")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   s := t.String()
   println(s == "2018-08-01 12:00:00 +0000 EDT")
}
```

> To avoid such problems, prefer time layouts that use a numeric zone offset,
> or use ParseInLocation.

```
package main
import "time"

func main() {
   { // example 1
      t, e := time.Parse(time.RFC1123Z, "Wed, 01 Aug 2018 12:00:00 -0400")
      if e != nil {
         panic(e)
      }
      s := t.String()
      println(s == "2018-08-01 12:00:00 -0400 -0400")
   }
   { // example 2
      ny, e := time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")
      if e != nil {
         panic(e)
      }
      t, e := time.ParseInLocation(time.RFC1123, "Wed, 01 Aug 2018 12:00:00 EDT", ny)
      if e != nil {
         panic(e)
      }
      s := t.String()
      println(s == "2018-08-01 12:00:00 -0400 EDT")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple debug run shows that it all comes down to this function `go/1.10/libexec/src/time/zoneinfo.go:226`

```
func (l *Location) lookupName(name string, unix int64) (offset int, ok bool) {
    l = l.get()

    // First try for a zone with the right name that was actually
    // in effect at the given time. (In Sydney, Australia, both standard
    // and daylight-savings time are abbreviated "EST". Using the
    // offset helps us pick the right one for the given time.
    // It's not perfect: during the backward transition we might pick
    // either one.)
    for i := range l.zone {
        zone := &l.zone[i]
        if zone.name == name {
            nam, offset, _, _, _ := l.lookup(unix - int64(zone.offset))
            if nam == zone.name {
                return offset, true
            }
        }
    }

    // Otherwise fall back to an ordinary name match.
    for i := range l.zone {
        zone := &l.zone[i]
        if zone.name == name {
            return zone.offset, true
        }
    }

    // Otherwise, give up.
    return
}
```

On my OSX (I am in Zurich, so `CET` as of now) the call to `l.get()` returns on object containing 4 values in the zone slice being `CET`, `CEST`, `CET` and `CEST` again. On top of that `GMT` and `UTC` are treated specially beforehand. All other zones are "unknown" to me, including EDT.

Comment: The follow up is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084928/parse-time-zone-into-a-location-struct-in-go

Comment: So the time zone identifier in the parse format is basically useless?  Either you need to have all timezones installed (how do you do that in Fedora?  Or any other Linux distribution?), or manually maintain a list.  Then one should just use location instead, even if that isn't exactly the same.

Comment: My OSX has all the timezones installed, but they are not used in Go beyond the current location or so it looks. The reason might well be the ambiguity which you pointed out to in comment to my follow up. In which case I would say, they should have dropped any timezone support from Parse or do it comprehensively where a 1:1 match exists, otherwise return an error.