# time format converted to strftime default format

Tags: go, strftime

In the wikipedia entry for [Common Log Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format), the strftime format is given as:

> [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] is the date, time, and time zone that the
>   request was received, by default in strftime format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S
>   %z.

When I try using the time.Format function:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, _ := time.Parse(time.UnixDate, "Tue Oct 10 13:55:36 PDT 2000")
    fmt.Println(time.Time(t).Format("01/Feb/2006:15:04:05 -0700"))
}
```

I get the output `[10/Feb/2000:13:55:36 +0000]`, while I was expecting `[10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700]` (per Wikipedia). What is wrong with my formatting?

I checked that day was a Tuesday and the time zone was -7h (PDT) for that date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Go's time.Parse() parse the timezone identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084316/why-doesnt-gos-time-parse-parse-the-timezone-identifier)

Comment: And the discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084928/parse-time-zone-into-a-location-struct-in-go

Comment: I think you are right about the dup for timezone but how about the month? Notice the month sticks to the formatted month string.

Comment: As answered below, use Jan instead of Feb, but timezone is still an issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the `Format` layout, `Jan` not `Feb`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, err := time.Parse(time.UnixDate, "Tue Oct 10 13:55:36 PDT 2000")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Time(t).Format("01/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700"))
}
```

Output:

```
10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 +0000
```

---

Also, for the time zone, use `ParseInLocation`,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    loc, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    t, err := time.ParseInLocation(time.UnixDate, "Tue Oct 10 13:55:36 PDT 2000", loc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
    fmt.Println(time.Time(t).Format("01/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700"))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/tBLw5oJSE5t

Output:

```
2000-10-10 13:55:36 -0700 PDT
10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700
```