# Parse time zone into a Location struct in Go

Tags: go, timezone

Given a time zone such as EDT or CEST is there a way to get a `time.Location` reference to use it to with `func (t Time) In(loc *Location) Time`?

It is possible to initialize the location for e.g. CEST with `time.LoadLocation("Europe/Berlin")` but how to do the same for the actual time zone notation?

Given the very insightful comment by @Svip is there any sensible way to return a list of representative location? That is for `WET` return e.g. `[Europe/London, Atlantik/Reykjavík]`. All other `WET` locations would follow the same time zone arrangements as one of those two.

Comment: That's problematic.  Say I enter 'WET', Western European Time, what then should the result be?  London?  But while the UK, Ireland and Portugal observes daylight savings time, Iceland - which is also in WET - does not.  So if an Icelandic developer uses WET to note time, it resulting in London would be problematic.  And you have the same problem with MST, as most of Arizona does not observe daylight savings time.

Comment: Fair enough. Changes my questions correspondingly. Any further insight?

Comment: These timezone abbreviations [are ambiguous](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations), which is why there is no support for them in the standard library. For instance, IST can mean any of Irish/Indian/Israel Standard Time.

Comment: this map is in the tree (unshared): https://golang.org/src/time/zoneinfo_abbrs_windows.go, generated by https://golang.org/src/time/genzabbrs.go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is option to parse time for given Location.
(https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocation)

```
type CustomTime struct {
    time.Time
}

const ctLayout = "Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm (MST)"

func (ct *CustomTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    s := strings.Trim(string(b), "\"")
    if s == "null" {
        ct.Time = time.Time{}
        return
    }
    location, err := time.LoadLocation("Local")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    ct.Time, err = time.ParseInLocation(ctLayout, s, location)
    return err
}
```

Comment: Will it work correctly if you provide time with timezone that does **not** correspond to the local timezone of the machine where this code is running?

Answer (score 3):

There exists a package [github.com/tkuchiki/go-timezone](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tkuchiki/go-timezone) that provides mapping between zone abbreviations and locations. See its [timezones.go](https://github.com/tkuchiki/go-timezone/blob/master/timezones.go).

However, as commenters also pointed out, abbreviated timezone names are ambiguous and it is better to avoid user input with such names at all. As mentioned in other questions ([Why doesn't Go's time.Parse() parse the timezone identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084316/why-doesnt-gos-time-parse-parse-the-timezone-identifier) and [How to properly parse timezone codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368415/how-to-properly-parse-timezone-codes)), when parsing time, Go correctly parses abbreviated timezone when it matches local timezone of the machine running code and `UTC` timezone. All others are not parsed correctly in my experience.

Comment: parsing one correctly while others are parsed (kind of) wrong honestly doesn't seem very *`go`* to me... related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66466330/10197418