# Why does Go time.Format return different value based on timezone?

Tags: go, time, timezone

I thought the Go [time.Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) should format time based on the layout. But seems it returns different value based on timezone info.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    formats := []string{
        time.RFC3339,
    }
    times := []string{
        "2020-03-08T01:59:50-08:00",
        "2020-03-08T01:59:59-08:00", //daylight saving starts 1 second later
        "2020-03-08T05:59:59-08:00",
    }
    for _, f := range formats {
        for _, t := range times {
            fmt.Printf("Format: %s\n", f)
            t, err := time.Parse(f, t)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("unix: %d\n", t.UnixNano())
            fmt.Printf("time: %s\n", t.Format(f))
            t = t.Add(time.Second)
            fmt.Printf("time + 1s: %s\n", t.Format(f))
        }
    }
}
```

Run output:

```
➜ go version
go version go1.15 darwin/amd64
➜ TZ=UTC go run main.go
Format: 2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00
unix: 1583661590000000000
time: 2020-03-08T01:59:50-08:00
time + 1s: 2020-03-08T01:59:51-08:00
Format: 2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00
unix: 1583661599000000000
time: 2020-03-08T01:59:59-08:00
time + 1s: 2020-03-08T02:00:00-08:00 (a: this is not expected)
unix: 1583675999000000000
time: 2020-03-08T05:59:59-08:00
time + 1s: 2020-03-08T06:00:00-08:00
➜ TZ=America/Los_Angeles go run main.go
Format: 2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00
unix: 1583661590000000000
time: 2020-03-08T01:59:50-08:00
time + 1s: 2020-03-08T01:59:51-08:00
Format: 2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00 
unix: 1583661599000000000
time: 2020-03-08T01:59:59-08:00
time + 1s: 2020-03-08T03:00:00-07:00 (b: this is expected)
Format: 2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00
unix: 1583675999000000000
time: 2020-03-08T05:59:59-08:00
time + 1s: 2020-03-08T06:00:00-08:00 (c: this contradicts with the b)
```

Comment: Why that value is not expected? `UTC` does not have daylight savings, so the formatted time is correct.

Comment: having another look at this, I'd say the `2020-03-08T03:00:00-07:00` is the result ***I would not expect***... it seems strange to me that one can set a time zone in this way. I mean, I'd expect the program to parse a string - which has no time zone information, just an offset! So why should this mysteriously introduce DST changes?

Comment: Thanks everyone! Updated to include a new time. Still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is documented. The output of `time.Format` is just a consequence, not the confusion's source - which is `time.Parse`:

[**func Parse**](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse):

> When parsing a time with a zone offset like -0700, if the offset
> corresponds to a time zone used by the current location (Local), then
> Parse uses that location and zone in the returned time. Otherwise it
> records the time as being in a fabricated location with time fixed at
> the given zone offset.

Further explanation can be found under
[**type Location**](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Location):

> Local represents the system's local time zone. On Unix systems, Local
> consults the TZ environment variable to find the time zone to use. No
> TZ means use the system default /etc/localtime. TZ="" means use UTC.
> TZ="foo" means use file foo in the system timezone directory.

Basically, go's parser tries to infer a time zone from a UTC offset. If the parsed UTC offset matches that of the time zone set by the `TZ` environment variable, this time zone is set in the returned `time`. Simplicity always seems to end when it comes to handling date & time.